# TIZEN to WEAR OS how send a POST JSON

Tags: post, wear-os

I am translating some app from TIZEN language to WEAR OS Google.
Some of that send a POST JSON to server.
In TIZEN with simply JS . . I am able to send data with WATCH connected to mobile device by Bluetooth connected to internet (mobile device), no app specific installed into mobile.
This is the code x TIZEN

```
function btnclicked(cmd) {
       switch (cmd) {
         case 'AA':
           json = '{"pop":"clock1"}';
         break;
         case 'BB':
           json = '{"pop":"clock2"}';
         break;
       }
       var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
       client.open("POST", "https://xxxxxxx.it:8132/yyy/qqqqq");
       client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       client.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) {
               alert(client.status);
            }
       }
       client.send(json);
    }
```

Now i try to "translate" into KOTLING with equivalent function

```
fun pushToChat(cmdx: String) {

val serverURL: String = "https://xxxxxxx.it:8132/yyy/qqqqq"
val url = URL(serverURL)
val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
connection.requestMethod = "POST"
connection.connectTimeout = 300000
connection.doOutput = true

val message = "{\"cmd\":\"$cmdx\"}"
val postData: ByteArray = message.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8")
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", postData.size.toString())
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")

try {
    val outputStream: DataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
    outputStream.write(postData)
    outputStream.flush()
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    Log.d("cmd1","Eccezione")
}



if (connection.responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && connection.responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
    try {
        val inputStream: DataInputStream = DataInputStream(connection.inputStream)
        val reader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        val output: String = reader.readLine()

        println("There was error while connecting")
        System.exit(0)

    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        throw Exception("Exception while push the notification  $exception.message")
    }
}


}
```

testing with emulator rise an exception on Log.d("cmd1","Eccezione")

Have to use other library like okHTTP or Retrofit?
I found some message (very old) that the issue could be because watch is not connetcted directly to net with Wi-Fi, but I need to use mobile device connection with internet (without dedicated app running on mobile device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this "unlock" i resolve the problem, now i need a fine tuning of the code, and verify on watch (with emulator it is ok)

```
val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find OkHttp much more intuitive to use.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/#post-to-a-server
https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-string-kt-java

```
        // Store this somewhere as a singleton
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request =
            Request.Builder()
                .url("https://xxxxxxx.it:8132/yyy/qqqqq")
                .post("{\"cmd\":\"$cmdx\"}".toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaType()))
                .build()

        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val output = response.body!!.string()
        }
```

Comment: very appreciate your fast reply . .. i test immediately, thanks Yuri